# get all occurrences of bigrams in Java

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to get all occurrences of a bigram out of a string.

So below I have some code which does some of it.

```
String testString = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.";

Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("\\w+ \\w+");
Matcher mat = pat.matcher(testString);

while (mat.find()) {
    System.out.println("Match: " + mat.group());
}
```

What I got was:

Match: Lorem ipsum

Match: dolor sit

Whereas the result I want is:

Match: Lorem ipsum

Match: ipsum dolor

Match: dolor sit

Match: sit amet

Comment: Does this have to be done with a single regular expression?  It would be straightforward using two.

Comment: I mean as long as it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match only every single word, instead of every combination of two.
Then keep the last word stored, and whenever a new word is found, store a doublet.

```java
String testString = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\w+");
Matcher matcher = pattern .matcher(testString);
String lastSingleWord = null;
List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();

while (matcher.find()) {
    String singleWord = matcher.group(0);
    if (lastSingleWord != null) {
        results.add(lastSingleWord + " " + singleWord);
    }
    lastSingleWord = singleWord;
}
```

Afterwards, if you want, you can output the list, or do with it as you please.

```java
results.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
// Lorem ipsum
// ipsum dolor
// dolor sit
// sit amet
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern `(?<= |^)(?=([^ ]+ [^ ]+))`

Explanation:

`(?<= |^)` - positive lookbehind, assert what preceeds is space or beginning of a string `^`

`(?=([^ ]+ [^ ]+))` - positive lookahead, assert what follows is: `[^ ]+` one or more characters other than space, space and again, one or more characters other than space

[Demo.](https://regex101.com/r/DwDtGt/1)

As suggested in comments, this pattern could be slightly simplified: `(?=\b([^ ]+ [^ ]+))`

[Another demo.](https://regex101.com/r/DwDtGt/1)

Comment: Couldn’t the lookbehind be replaced with a word boundary, `\\b`?

Comment: @VGR You are right :) Updated answer.